# How can I create folders during installation process?

Tags: c#, winforms

I know that some folders will create during the setup process by using Setup Project, but I want to create another folder. For example, in C:\Users\User Name\Document.Plus,i want to use code to create it. I'm new to programming. I hope you will help me to achieve it. Thanks

Comment: Please show example code of what you have tried.

Comment: You'll need to use [custom  action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some third Party tool to create an executable file:

1. If the tool has an option to create a new folder then you are lucky.
2. You can create a folder in your code-behind when your project opens
   the  first time, if you have the right permissions that target the
       directory you want.

I suggest do create a folder upon your Project `run` on the first time using **Code Behind**